# How to upload edited vendor folders with Laravel Envoyer

Tags: php, git, laravel, forge, envoyer.io

I'm trying to upload my edited (custom) versions of some vendor packages
 Example I edited some code in

```
vendor/misd/linkify/src/Misd/Linkify
```

I changed a few lines to work for my project.
The problem is when i push my project to github then deploy using envoyer , All the vendor files get reinstalled via composer update, thus grabbing from the GitHub repo

I need to be able to upload my own version of that specific vendor folder/file

I've tried whitelisting specific vendor file via gitignore , heres my original question [Uploading Specific Vendor files with Laravel's Envoyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415546/uploading-specific-vendor-files-with-laravels-envoyer)

But with no luck. Is this good practice, should I be going about it a different way? How can I get my modified version up to my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have write access to the Vendor Project, you won't be able to push changes. You need to fork the Misd/Linkify vendor project and make changes and push to your fork.

Then use Composers [Repository Package pattern](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) and provide the path to the forked project.

If it is a private repository refer https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories